# Repeated pattern in python regex

Tags: python, regex

New to python regex and would like to write something that matches this

`<name>.name.<age>.age@<place>`

I can do this but would like the pattern to have and check name and age.

```
pat = re.compile("""
       ^(?P<name>.*)
        \.
        (?P<name>.*)
        \.
        (?P<age>.*)
        \.
        (?P<age>.*?)
        \@
        (?P<place>.*?)
        $""", re.X)
```

I then match and extract the values. 
`res = pat.match('alan.name.65.age@jamaica')`

Would like to know the best practice to do this?

Comment: What's the point of repeating the `(?P<name>.*)` group?

Comment: I've edited it. The argument to `match` is my requirement. Its a pattern with name and age being always present, hence would like to check it. @Tomalak

Comment: Ahh, the *substring* `'.name'` is always present, I see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Match `.name` and `.age` literally. You don't need new groups for that.

```
pat = re.compile("""
       ^(?P<name>[^.]*)\.name
        \.
        (?P<age>[^.]*)\.age
        \@
        (?P<place>.*)
        $""", re.X)
```

Notes

- I've replaced `.*` ("anything") by `[^.]*` ("anything except a dot"), because the dot cannot really be part of the name in the pattern you show.
- Think whether you mean `*` (0-unlimited occurrences) or rather `+` (1-unlimited occurrences).

Answer (score 2):

No reason not to allow `.` in names, e.g. `John Q. Public`.

```
import re

pat = re.compile(r"""(?P<name>.*?)\.name
                 \.(?P<age>\d+)\.age
                 @(?P<place>.*$)""",
                 flags=re.X)
m = pat.match('alan.name.65.age@jamaica')
print(m.group('name'))
print(m.group('age'))
print(m.group('place'))
```

Prints:

```
alan
65
jamaica
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need the groups if you use re.split :

```
re.split('\.name\.|\.age', "alan.name.65.age@jamaica")
```

This will return name and age as first two elements of the list.